# Firefox window.innerHeight is too small

Tags: javascript, firefox, svg

I'm working on some javascript svg graphics here, and I'm finding that I really can't depend on the value of window.innerHeight(or outerHeight) on Firefox.  I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 with firefox 18.0.1, and on a 1366x768 screen firefox returns a window.innerHeight value of 283.  Chrome, on the same screen, returns 656.  Is there any reason for this massive discrepency?  I've searched around trying to find anyone with this issue, but all I found was a closed jquery [ticket](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/13333).  Here's a skeleton of the code I'm using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="border-width: 0px; margin: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<!-- Head with some scripts and style -->
<body>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
style="position:absolute; width:100%; height:100%"
xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events" version="1.1" baseProfile="full"
preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet"
viewBox="0 0 1400 700"
onload="Initialize(evt)">
  <script type="text/ecmascript"><![CDATA[
    Bunch of javascript here
  ]]></script>
<!-- SVG Element definitions -->
</svg>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is it possible that you've zoomed on this page?  Zooming changes the innerHeight in CSS pixels...

Comment: That was it!  Thanks for the help-- if you post this as an answer then I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is probably (well, definitely given the comments above) use of the browser's zoom, which changes the size of a CSS pixel and hence the size of the viewport in CSS pixels.